# how to run .bat file(path contains space) through vbs

Tags: vbscript

Iam trying to run  a VB script which is calling a .bat file. But the path of .bat file contains white spaces due to which vbs is failing to run, showing an error as "File not found". Please help.
The path of .bat file cannot be changed

Comment: Could you share the code you are using to call the batch file?

Comment: Generally speaking you put double double quotes if run from script. e.g. `"""" & "C:\Test Folder\Test Script.vbs" & """"` or just `"""C:\Test Folder\Test Script.vbs"""`

Answer (score 2):

Put the path between quotes. The first `"` creates the opening tag for the string, the second `"` is an escape character, so the third `"` will be placed in the string. So the content of the string will eventualy be `"C:\Folder Folder\My Script.bat"` instead of `C:\Folder Folder\My Script.bat`

```
Set sshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sshShell.Run """C:\Folder Folder\My Script.bat"""
```